# Creating a Screenshot Plugin

Tags: firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, screen-capture

Does anyone have a good tutorial on creating a simple screen capture plugin for Firefox and/or Chrome?

Comment: Some sample code to get you going would be found in the source of https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-preview/

Answer (score 5):

Here's a snippet for Firefox. In your overlay XUL add:

```
    <html:canvas id="my-canvas" style="display: none;" />
```

Then in your overlay javascript, [listen for new document loads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load) and this snippet will save the screenshot to a file:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //Find the window dimensions
    canvas.height = doc.defaultView.innerHeight; //doc is the content document that you listened for
    canvas.width = doc.defaultView.innerWidth;

    context.drawWindow(doc.defaultView, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");

    //Create a data url from the canvas
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Read about nsiIOService and nsiWebBrowserPersist to create an nsiURI from data url and then persist it locally.

Answer (score 2):

There's a sample extension on how to do this with Chrome http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/samples.html#e1697cacebad05218798bf3e8a0f724517f0e8c3

Answer (score 1):

No sure about Firefox, but in Chrome extension you can capture a tab with [`chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab), which would return image in [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) format. After that you would be able to manipulate the image with [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) element, if needed.